# How is this generic array legal?

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

The problem of generic arrays (i.e., the impossibility of them) seems to be a recurring theme for me. Below is the relevant code of a HashMap data structure. Obviously, I cannot declare a `Bucket[]`, since generic arrays are impossible. However, I can declare a `MapThing.Bucket[]`. Am I correct when I assert that this is good practice, since even though `MapThing.Bucket[]` is a raw type declaration, the actual `MapThing.Bucket[]` instance is type parameterized by its enclosing instance?

Thanks for any insight!!!

Chris

```
public class MapThing<K, V> {
  private Bucket buckets[];

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    MapThing<String, Integer> thing = new MapThing<>();
    thing.put("got your number", 8675309);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public MapThing() {
    buckets = new MapThing.Bucket[314159];
  }

  public void put(K key, V value) {
    Bucket bucket = new Bucket(key, value);

    // Prints typeof bucket key: String, value: Integer
    System.out.println("typeof bucket key: "
    + bucket.getKey().getClass().getSimpleName() + ", value: "
    + bucket.getValue().getClass().getSimpleName());

    buckets[Math.abs(key.hashCode() % buckets.length)] = bucket;
  }

  private class Bucket {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    Bucket(K key, V value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
      return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You certainly can declare a `Bucket` array, why did you think you couldn't? You are using a Raw Type and you shouldn't do that.

Comment: The actual array knows _nothing_ about generics.

Comment: No, I cannot declare a Bucket array:
Bucket[] buckets = new Bucket[12]; // gives following error:
"Cannot create a generic array of MapThing<K,V>.Bucket"

Comment: Try declaring `Bucket` as `private class Bucket<K,V> {`, then you can use something like `private Bucket<K,V> buckets[];` and `buckets = new Bucket[10];`...

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the typical "cannot create generic array" error.

Comment: If you write `buckets = new Bucket[10]`, it should work with a warning, which is more or less the way it's going to be.

Comment: `buckets = new Bucket[10]` produces "Cannot create a generic array of MapThing<K,V>.Bucket."

Comment: Did you redeclare `Bucket` to take parameters?

Comment: Ah.  `Bucket` should probably be static, then.

Comment: Why should it be static? When it is not static and not generic, its instances use the type parameters of its enclosing instance.

Comment: Make Bucket a static class.  Then it does not include a reference to a MapThing and does not need to be generified.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, I cannot declare a Bucket[], since generic arrays are
>   impossible.

1. You can ALWAYS *declare a variable* of *any* array type. Always. It is perfectly fine to declare variables of `Bucket[]` or `ArrayList<String>[]` or whatever.
2. You cannot use the array creation expression (i.e. `new X[...]`) with a parameterized type (i.e. if `X` is `Something<SomethingElse>` where `SomethingElse` is anything except `?`). You *can* use array creation expression with a raw type (i.e. `new X[...]` where `X` is a raw type), e.g. `new ArrayList[10]`.

   Therefore, if `Bucket` were a raw type, then `new Bucket[10]` would be perfectly fine. The thing is, `Bucket` is not a raw type. `Bucket` is a non-static inner class inside a generic outer class. That means it is within the scope of the type parameters of its outer class. In other words, if you write the unqualified type `Bucket` inside `MapThing`, it implicitly means `MapThing<K,V>.Bucket`, which is a *parameterized* type.

   To get the raw type, you need to explicitly qualify it with the outer class, as in `MapThing.Bucket`. So `new MapThing.Bucket[10]` will work.

   Alternately, if you don't want to use raw types, you can parameterize it with all wildcards: `new MapThing<?,?>.Bucket[10]`.